# PerfenceyActivity cannot show in TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, preferenceactivity, activitygroup

everybody I have a problerm when I put a PreferenceActivity in a TabHost.The PreferenceActivity cannot show,other Atcitivites whice in TabHost can show normally,And I have tested the PreferenceActivity independently,It can show normally, I have search the problerm by google,and I dinn't get the answer,anyone wound tell me the reason? thanks.
   My TobHostAcitvity code is like this:

```
public class TabsActivity extends Activity {

protected static final String tag = "maps";

Context context = null;

LocalActivityManager manager = null;

ViewPager pager = null;

TabHost tabHost = null;

protected int currentItemId;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager);
    manager = new LocalActivityManager(this, true);
    manager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = TabsActivity.this;
    initiaTabHost();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

}

private View getView(String id, Intent intent) {
    return manager.startActivity(id, intent).getDecorView();
}

public void initiaTabHost() {

    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();
    tabHost.setup(manager);
    Intent it1 = new Intent(context, WifiSearchAcitivity.class);
    it1.putExtra("name", WifiSearchAcitivity.tag);
    Intent it2 = new Intent(context, MapActivity.class);
    it2.putExtra("name", MapActivity.tag);
    Intent it3 = new Intent(context, MyPreferenceActivity.class);
    it3.putExtra("name", MyPreferenceActivity.tag);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("列表").setIndicator("列表")
            .setContent(it1));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("地图").setIndicator("地图")
            .setContent(it2));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("设置").setIndicator("设置")
            .setContent(it3));
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            log(tag, "onTabChange called id= " + tabId);
            if (WifiSearchAcitivity.tag.equals(tabId)) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(0);
            } else if (MapActivity.tag.equals(tabId)) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(1);
            } else if (MyPreferenceActivity.tag.equals(tabId)) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(2);

            }
        }
    });

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpage);
    final ArrayList<View> list = new ArrayList<View>();
    list.add(getView(WifiSearchAcitivity.tag, it1));
    list.add(getView(MapActivity.tag ,it2));
    list.add(getView(MyPreferenceActivity.tag ,it3));

    pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
            /*
             * log(tag, "destroyItem called arg1="+arg1); ViewPager
             * pViewPager = ((ViewPager) arg0);
             * pViewPager.removeView(list.get(arg1));
             */
        }

        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
            log(tag, "finishupdate called");
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // log(tag, "getcount called");
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1) {
            log(tag, " instantiateItem called arg1= " + arg1);
            ViewPager pViewPager = ((ViewPager) arg0);
            if (pViewPager.getChildCount() == 0) {// pViewPager.removeAllViews();
                for (View view : list) {
                    pViewPager.addView(view);
                }
            }
            return list.get(arg1);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            // log(tag, "isViewfromObject called " + (arg0 == arg1));
            return arg0 == arg1;
        }

        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
        }
    });

    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            log(tag, "onPageChangeListener called " + arg0);
            currentItemId = arg0;
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

}
```

}